# MS ACCESS - changing data dynamically in the form

Tags: sql, ms-access

My form is divided by Form Header, Detail section and Form Footer (design mode). All table fields are listed in Detail section.

I have to make it works this way - when I am clicking on person's name (shown as hyperlink) Detail section has to show me records from table, where name field value is equal one that I clicked. The number of the shown fields should stay the same.

I wrote a procedure on VB:

```
Private Sub GE_PERSON_Click()

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT GENERIC.GE_ID, GENERIC.GE_OPEN AS [OPEN], Workforce.WF_NAME AS PERSON, [GENERIC].[GE_DATEIN] AS RECEIVED, GENERIC.GE_DATEREQUESTED AS [STARTING DATE], GENERIC.GE_CONSECUTIVE AS CONSECUTIVE, GENERIC.GE_AMOUNT AS [DAYS TAKEN], ABSENCE.AB_TYPE AS [ABSENCE TYPE], [GENERIC].[GE_STATUS] AS STATUS"
strSQL = strSQL + "FROM (GENERIC INNER JOIN Workforce ON GENERIC.[GE_PERSON] = Workforce.[WF_ID]) INNER JOIN ABSENCE ON GENERIC.[GE_TYPE] = ABSENCE.[AB_ID]"
strSQL = strSQL + "WHERE WORKFORCE.[WF_NAME] = " + Form_GENERIC.GE_PERSON
strSQL = strSQL + "ORDER BY GENERIC.GE_DATEREQUESTED;"

Form_GENERIC.RecordSource = strSQL 

End Sub
```

When I assign the `strSQL` to the `Form_GENERIC.RecordSource` I receive an error. I can't send data from formed string to the main form GENERIC Record Source - it causing error

> Runtime Error 3141:The SELECT statement include reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect

Definitely need your help guys!

Comment: How are related records displayed? Is there a subform? Your form description is not sufficient to generate a definitive answer.

Comment: Let me see if I got this... When you click the `NAME` field, it will filter the current form(You didn't mention if there is a subform, if its a divided subform or what will show the filtered records). Assuming it is in spreadsheet mode.

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570)

Answer (score 1):

When you concatenate strings make sure you include a space at the beginning or end of each line. Otherwise the strings are pushed together causing the error you are seeing.

E.g. if you do this

```
strSQL = "SELECT field1, field2"
strSQL = strSQL + "FROM table"
```

You end up with this

```
"SELECT field1, field2FROM table"
```

Add a space to prevent the error

```
strSQL = "SELECT field1, field2"
strSQL = strSQL + " FROM table"
                   ^
                   put a space at the start of each concatenated line
```